# Storing audit logs inexpensively

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We're running a web application in Azure. Due to federal compliance regulations, we need to create a record every time someone changes a setting in our software.

These logs will likely be huge, so we don't want to pay a ton of money for a SQL server database. They also will only be queried across a date range, so we don't need fancy RDBMS features, or even NoSQL ones.

What's the best option for storing data? In flat files? E.g., break each file into one named `<account_id>_<month>_<sequence_num>.txt` and stuff it all into that? I know you're not supposed to roll your own database, but this is an optimization. In big CosmosDB JSON files?

I just want to get a sense of what the prevailing wisdom out there is like, and if there are any off-the-shelf components I should look into using.

Answer (score 3):

You could store it in json files on Azure Blob Storage. There are several tiers you can choose from, one being [Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers#archive-access-tier) which could be an option. Or the cold tier.

It is one of the [cheapest](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/) data stores. It can be explored using the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows).

You can access the data using a range of tools including, but not limited to, Power Bi, Excel, Azure Data Lake Analytics etc.

For the (rare?) occasions you need to query the data you could write [an u-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-get-started) job using Azure Data Lake Analytics.

We store terabytes of unstructured application log data this way and use u-sql for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cosmosdb for the same. In one of our application we are using it for the same purpose.

You can create a collection named 'ActivityLog' and add your entries to the same. You can have field for the different entries you need and sort them accordingly.

Comment: won't it be too expensive to query such logs? we also used to have logs in cosmos, but after a while switched to azure blob storage in order to reduce costs